# mobile referer in ios

Tags: ios, app-store

I have iOS application that I would like to promote on different web-sites.

In Google Store I can record [Campaign name](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns) and use it in application. I'm looking for something similar for iOS but I can't find.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933191/april-2014-ios-7-is-there-a-way-to-track-conversions-of-ios-apps-to-attribute

Comment: Please visit this, It may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933191/april-2014-ios-7-is-there-a-way-to-track-conversions-of-ios-apps-to-attribute

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526723/how-to-track-marketing-efforts-for-iphone-apps-on-the-app-store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [Mobile App Tracker](http://mobileapptracking.com). It has ability to track publishers statistics. For example it could track how many users installed your app, first sales, custom events and etc. from each promote web site,

Answer (score 3):

There is a Google Analytics SDK for iOS. [This link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns) leads to the iOS page for campaign measurement in Google Analytics. As far as I can tell, it works exactly the same as the Android SDK that you linked to in your question. Good luck!

Comment: not really... This is how to create campaigns in application but not how to receive traffic sources from WEB. Meaning, I can't calculate traffic coming from web but i can if it's from app.
That is what I understand from that link...